# Closing file descriptors when handling pipes in c

Tags: c, process, pipe, signals

I'm trying to implement a very simple shell which only handles pipes, and with no syntax errors, so I have an AST declared this way:

```
typedef struct s_ast t_ast;

struct s_ast
{
    int     type;
    t_ast   *l;
    t_ast   *r;
    char    **cmd;
};
```

`type` can only hold 0 or 1 (CMD or PIPE).
`l`and `r` are the left / right branches of the pipe if `type`is equal to PIPE
`cmd` is the command with arguments if `type`is equal to CMD

Then I have my exe function that simply calls one of two other functions: `exe_pipe` or `exe_cmd`.
The `exe_cmd` function simply calls `execve` in a child process and waits it to end.

Now, here's my `exe_pipe` function (without error checking on syscalls for more readability):

```
void exe_pipe(t_ast *ast, char **env)
{
    int fd[2], pid[2];

    pipe(fd);
    if ((pid[0] = fork()) == 0)
    {
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        exe(ast->l, env);
        close(fd[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILRE);
    }
    if ((pid[1] = fork()) == 0)
    {
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[1]);
        exe(ast->r, env);
        close(fd[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
    close(fd[0]); close(fd[1]);
    waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
}
```

Basically, I'm forking twice to create 2 "subshells" and each ones will execute its side of the pipe.

My problem is that this code leaks some file descriptors, but I don't figure out where to close each ones, I guess I have to use `SIGPIPE` signal somewhere but I'm not comfortable with it.

You can find the full code [here](https://gitlab.com/bccyv/microshell) if you want to test it

Comment: "this code leaks some file descriptors" how do you know?

Comment: If I execute a command with a lot of pipes, pipe() fails because I have too many open files

Comment: " I have my exe function that simply calls one of two other functions". Well that's a lie. Before calling the other function It calls `dup` twice, and the resulting fds are never closed. closed. `close(fd[0]); close(fd[1]);` is also a lie, your real code does something completely different.

Comment: my `exe` function actually just calls `exe_cmd` or `exe_pipe`, `dup` calls are made into `exe_pipe` function.
Why `close(fd[0]); close(fd[1]);` is a lie ? Where my code does something different?

Comment: src/execution/execute lines 36, 37: `fd[0] = dup(0); fd[1] = dup(1);` never closed. srcs/execution/pipeline.c line 57: `close(fexit == pid[1] ? fd[0] : fd[1]);` closes one of the two descriptors. That's precisely the descriptors that are leaked. Please post a [mcve], until that time I'm voting to close this.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong project, but it's my fault, the good one were private, my bad, now it's ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close a file descriptor after you dup it.  The boiler plate is:

```
pipe(fd);
...
dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
close(fd[0]);
close(fd[1]);
execl(....)
```

Since you are executing your children before you close the pipe, you have too many fd open when you call `exe`.  In particular, the first child still has `fd[1]` open while it is executing, and since that file descriptor is still open the second child will never see EOF on its stdin.  (I assume the `exe` calls an `exec*`.  If that's the case, it doesn't do any good to call `close` after `exe`.)

Always count your fd.  Assume you start with 3. (0, 1, and 2).  After the call to `pipe`, you have 5.  After you `dup2`, you still have 5. (One was opened by `dup2`, and one was closed.)   You want to have only 3 when the child executes, so you need to close 2.

Comment: My exe function can call `exe_cmd` that calls `execve` if the left or right branch of the pipe isn't another pipe, yes. You're true, it don't make sense to close a file descriptor after an `exec` call, but if I close both read end and write end of the pipe before calling `exec`, I'll not be able to share i/o with the other process, Am I right?

Comment: @bccyv No, that's not correct.  That's the whole point of the dup2.  In one child, you close the read end of the pipe because you're not going to use it.  You dup the write end of the pipe to stdout because you are going to use it, and you then close the write end of the pipe because you are going to use the duplicate.  In the other child, you do the same with the other end of the pipe and stdin. You dup the one you're going to use, and you don't need 2 copies of it so you close one of them.

Comment: I miss something, `dup2` duplicates `fildes2` and assign it to `filedes`, right? So if I `dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);`, it duplicates `STDIN_FILENO` into `fd[0]`, then if I close `fd[0]`, as `dup2` also closes `filedes2,` I am not supposed to get any file descriptor open. I know I'm wrong because tour answer is correct and fixed my issue, but where's my error?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195057/what-is-an-open-file-description

Comment: @bccyv In short, closing `fd[0]` does not close the duplicate.